# ¿En que formato se introduce la fecha en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

En clase trabajamos con java y hemos empezado con las bases de datos, utilizamos la biblioteca Driver MySQL JDBD (No se si esto influye en algo, perdonad mi desconocimiento) y me gustaría saber a la hora de introducir una fecha en una tabla, en que orden se introduce el día, mes y año.
Según tengo entendido sería 'aaaa/mm/dd'. Espero que alguien pueda confirmarmelo o corregirme, un saludo.

Comment: Sergio, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Lo que preguntas dependerá de varios escenarios posibles. Dando por supuesto que se trata una columna del tipo `Date` en la BD, siempre tendrás que crear una fecha formateada adecuadamente y pasarla a la BD. [En esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18615191/5587982) tienes algunos ejemplos. +

Comment: Hola Sergio, como bien ha comentado @A.Cedano (uno de los grandes de esta comunidad) la respuesta dependerá de muchos factores, en el link que ha dejado de SO se explica bastante bien, si necesitas ayudas con las traducciones no dudes en pedirlo. Por otro lado cuando tengas unos minutos, te recomiendo mirar [ask] y hacer el [tour], así además conseguirás tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente el formato es:
''YYYY-MM-DD''

Pero de acuerdo al propio manual de MySQL:

> Los valores de fecha y hora se pueden representar en varios formatos, como texto con comillas o como números, dependiendo del tipo exacto del valor y otros factores. Por ejemplo, en contextos en los que MySQL espera una fecha, interpreta '2015-07-21','20150721' y 20150721 como fechas.

Para fecha y hora el formato es el siguiente:
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' o igualmente 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

En caso que necesites insertar la fecha/fecha y hora actual de algún campo de tu base de datos puedes hacerlo con now():

Ejemplo:

> INSERT INTO usuarios (alias_usuario, contra_usuario, fecha_registro_usuario)
>   VALUES('peluso', 'peluso3000', NOW())

Referencias:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246309/mysql-insert-current-date-time